# Non-deterministic Turing machine and palindromes

Tags: turing-machines, decision-problem

I have to design a Non-deterministic Turing machine that accepts only non-palindromes in $NTime(n\log n)$.

I think this would be easy on a 2-tape DTM. Simply copy the string onto the second tape – $O(n)$ time – and then check both tapes (one from beginning and the second from the end) – $O(n)$ time again.

However, I can't picture how to do such procedure in a non-deterministic TM using only one tape. All the procedures I came up with take $O(n^2)$ steps. How can the non-determinism reduce the running time here?

Comment: If a string is a non-palindrome then it fails to be a palindrome in one (or more) places. Use the non-determinism to guess where this place is.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That makes sense. But in that case, you will have to pick a symbol on the tape and check it with the appropriate symbol on the other end of the tape. How do you save the position? You cannot save it in a state since the length is variable and you have fixed number of states...

Comment: Possibilities: 1) Construct a PDA and simulate it with a TM. 2) Construct a 2-tape TM and simulate it with a regular TM. (Both simulations are textbook material.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guess a position $\ell$ and add it to the left of the input. Copy it to the beginning of the tape, on top of the input string (use an expanded alphabet). Now go to position $\ell$, carrying your counter around with you. For each position you move, you need to spend $O(\log n)$ time to copy the counter, but that's fine. Decrementing the counter and comparing it to zero also take only $O(\log n)$. Once at position $\ell$, remember the symbol there, and go back to the beginning. Now move your counter all the way to the other end of the string, and count $\ell$ positions from there. Compare the symbol you find to the one you remember.

Comment: One more concern: I can have an expanded alphabet looking like this (symbol, counter value) but this alphabet will still be finite and bounded by some constant. If the input string is long enough, I will not have big enough number for the counter, right?

Comment: You are going to store the counter in binary, so the "overlay tape" only needs two or three symbols.

Comment: I cant imagine how this alphabet would look like... did you mean it like this? <symbol, 001><symbol, 010> etc?

Comment: It is enough for each cell in the overlay tape to contain one bit. The counter occupies $O(\log n)$ cells on the overlay tape, which keep moving as you move along the input tape.

Comment: Ok, I get that, but I still cannot see how this solves the problem. The alphabet is still finite and the counter has fixed number of digits. The input could be longer than the counter will be able to store. And size of the alphabet, of course, should not depend on the length of the input... I cannot simply add another digit to the counter because the alphabet must be fixed before the input is processed!

Comment: No, the counter doesn't have a fixed number of digits, it has $O(\log n)$ bits, and each bit is stored in its own cell. The counter occupies $O(\log n)$ cells on the tape. This is why the running time is $O(n\log n)$ rather than $O(n)$. At this point I suggest you spend a few hours thinking about the matter.

Comment: Yes, I got it now... thats why I deleted my last comment straight ahead... I will think about it but I think it may be the answer. I will accept once I get down to it later. Thanks for your time and explanation!